# Configure logwatch to only email when there is something to report

Tags: logwatch

Is there a way to get logwatch, instead of always sending a daily report, to only email a report when there is a problem, i.e. the filtered logs aren't empty?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly the answer you want, but: use logcheck instead.  It does exactly that (filters out all normal logs and only e-mails anything leftover).

Comment: Thanks, will check it out. Hopefully the documentation is better than for logwatch!